# What does it mean for a ring to have an involution? Are there any examples?

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, definition, involutions

A ring $R$ is said to be a ring with an involution if there exists a mapping 
$*\colon R  \to  R$ such that for every $a, b \in R$:

- $a^{**} = a$,
- $(a + b)^* = b^* +  a^*$,
- $(ab)^* = b^*a^*$.

Can anyone please explain this definition with an example?

Answer (score 11):

An involution is a so-called anti-homomorphism (that's what that last condition expresses) that, if applied twice, gives the identity map. Note that your second condition is the same as $(a+b)^* = a^*+b^*$ – addition is commutative!

As a typical example, let $n$ be a natural number, let $A$ be any ring, and consider the ring of $n$-by-$n$ matrices over $A$. The transpose is an involution on that ring. Another classical example: on the ring of [Hamilton quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion), the map $a+bi+cj+dk \mapsto a-bi-cj-dk$ [is an involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Conjugation,_the_norm,_and_reciprocal).

If the ring is commutative, then an involution is just a ring automorphism (an invertible homomorphism from the ring to itself) of order 2.

Answer (score 2):

An involution is a map which is it's own inverse. For example consider the complex number with the complex conjugation as involution:
It's easy to check that complex conjugation satisfies the properties of involution.

Comment: So this is what I have understood that if we consider an identity map then $3* = 3$. What if we consider $R = Z_6$, what will be the matrix $A*$ if matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: If by "map" you mean a ring homomorphism, then that's not the usual definition of involution. Unless the ring is commutative, an involution is not a ring homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

An easy example is $(\mathbb C, *)$ where $*$ is the conjugate operator.

Comment: Amanda, I know it has been a long time since you asked this question. I was wondering I know a reference about involution for a ring. Thank you in advance